# How to fetch an image from an API

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I fetch an image from the API I receive the image name, not the full image.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.150:8080/crm/api/itemsapi.php',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      var items = data.data;
      for (var key in items) {
        $('.Data').append("ITEM NAME : " + items[key].itemname + "<br/>" + "ITEM PRICE : " + items[key].price + "<br/>" + "ITEM DISCRIPTION : " + items[key].discription + "<br/>" + items[key].itemimage + "<br/> <br/>");
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: To make this work you need to change what your server side PHP logic is returning, this isn't a JS issue. Also note that you cannot directly return binary image data in an AJAX request. I'd suggest returning a path to the image, or researching how to base64 encode the image and return it from the PHP in that format ready to be displayed on the site

Comment: @kunal Bisht  Please let me know items[key].itemimage  is what is img URL or base64.  if it's the only name so you need to append the img URL along with folder name like (u store the image on the server and you return only name (items[key].itemimage) so Img URL is "http://www.example.com/imgfolder/"+items[key].itemimage ) and put this URL into Img HTML Tag :)